# Как сделать изменение пароля Laravel?

Tags: laravel

Все привет... Как сделать изменение пароля с подтверждение по email'у?

Есть форма, в ней вводим текущий и новый пароль и жмем на кнопку. Как сделать чтоб после нажатия на почту приходило письмо с ссылкой на подтверждение, после перехода по ссылке соответственно изменялся. Что для этого необходимо сделать?

И еще один вопрос: Как сделать сброс пароля?
По стандарту в laravel есть модалка для сброса, жму, ввожу email, который существует в бд, и показывает вот эту ошибку, что делать?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По первому вопросу, могу предложить следующий алгоритм.
Создать два поля в таблице password и например password_new. Когда пользователь меняет пароль, Вы записываете его в поле password_new. Дальше посылаете ему емейл с подтверждением. И когда он подтверждает, просто копируете поле password_new в поле password.

По 2 вопросу, у Вас в .env файле наверняка не проставлены доступы к почте

Например:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=MyUsername@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=MyPassword
```

**ПРИМЕЧАНИЕ. Не забудьте перезапустить сервер после редактирования .env файла, чтобы он отобрал новые данные, которые вы там разместили.**

Comment: А поле MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null?

Comment: @Евгений MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls, если gmail. Для других почтовых сервисов, смотрите их документацию